# condition inside Ngfor loop

Tags: angular7

*ngFor="!FieldAdvicelength && let fA of FieldAdvice ; let id =index"

When I am using this `*ngfor` it is throwing error, I need for loop should only apply when FieldAdvice length is greater than zero. How to do it?

```html
<tr [ngClass]="{'tableheadings':isOther,'faheadings':isfieldasst}" 
   *ngFor="let fA of FieldAdvice ; let id =index">
                                    
   <td *ngIf="FieldAdvicelength && RoleId=='AD' && !el.IsChecked?true:RoleId=='AD' && (enableEdit && enableEditIndex==el.name+i)">
      <input type="text"  class='inputtext' formControlName="Advice"   placeholder="Type Advice here">
   </td>
   <td *ngIf="FieldAdvicelength && RoleId=='AD'?false:((RoleId=='EP'|| RoleId=='AD'|| RoleId=='FA' || RoleId=='FR' ) && (RoleId!=='AD' || !enableEdit || enableEditIndex !==el.name+i)) && !el.IsChecked">
      <span style="color:grey" *ngIf="fA.advice==''">Type Advice here</span> 
      <span style="color:grey"> {{fA.advice}}</span> 
   </td>
```

I need to display these row eventhough FieldAdvicelength is zero but ngfor loop should apply only FieldAdvicelength is greater than zero

Answer (score 0):

Remove the condition from your `*ngFor` and add an `*ngIf="!FieldAdvicelength"` to your tag.

```
<div *ngIf="!FieldAdvicelength" *ngFor="let fA of FieldAdvice ; let id =index">
...
</div>
```

Comment: If the whole row must be skipped, put the `*ngIf` on the `<tr>`tag. If the cell must be skipped, put the `*ngIf` on the `<td>`. Make sure that the value of `FieldAdvicelength` is indeed the correct value. Maybe make it more verbose by putting in `FieldAdvicelength > 0`.

Comment: Also, if there is an error, please include said error.